# Beamer not working at all!

Tags: beamer, errors, pdftex, compiling, input-encodings

Suddenly I am getting the cryptic "Text line contains an invalid character" errors (100 of them) on all my beamer files. Even this MWE doesn't work right:

```
\documentclass{beamer} 

\begin{document} 

Sample document. 

\end{document}
```

I am using the latest TeXnicCenter (2.02 stable) and Miktex 2.9 - what has gone wrong?

My feeling is that something is screwed up with the encodings but I can't figure out what.

UPDATE: Texmaker doesn't work either, giving this error:
"A funny symbol that I can't read has just been input."

Comment: Did it say exactly which lines are problematic

Comment: Just for the fun of it, what happens if you use the Texmaker or texstudio editors?

Comment: @daleif Texmaker fails as well. They all blame line 1.

Comment: What is the encode shown by TeXmaker? You can read it on the status bar.

Comment: @Sigur It's UTF-8 (Normal Mode if it's relevant)

Comment: Try this on preamble `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` (no dash before 8).

Comment: @Sigur Ok - Tried it, but no dice :(

Comment: The problem is only with beamer class or also with report? I guess that you have a broken compiler.

Comment: Try `\begin{frame}Sample document.\end{frame}`

Comment: @Sigur report and article work fine; frame does not make any difference, I am afraid.

Comment: You could look with a hex editor, if you have a [Byte Order Mark (BOM)](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_Order_Mark) at the start of your file. You shouldn't have one of those.

Comment: Can you post the log file from trying to process the MWE?

Comment: When was the last time you updated miktex?

Comment: @JuriRobl How does one do that?

Comment: @daleif Probably a long time ago. Is there a patch or something I am missing?

Comment: @FelixGoldberg  Not a patch as such, but it seems that something is corrupt at your end. An update might fix it. You could also make a zip including the `.tex` and the `.log` files and then send it to me by email.

Answer (score 3):

Having seen the `.tex` file, there is no problem with the code. The `.log` on the other hand reveals that the culprit is `ifpdf.sty`, after receiving `ifpdf.sty` by email we can conclude it is corrupt. In my emacs all the file contains is `^@`.

I recommend a MikTeX reinstall, or even moving to TL (just because I generally prefer TL over MikTeX even on Windows).

Comment: Thanks a lot for putting time and effort into this. Is there a way to fix the mess without reinstalling engines? Say, would re-installing the ifpdf package suffice?

Comment: We have no idea if there are other packages that are messed up, so it would be better to reinstall. Also your `beamer` is from 2010, there has been a lot of updates since then.